# Infinity/Loop scroll ViewPager with Fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I add two fragments to my ViewPagerAdapter in my main_activity
I use the [LoopingViewPager](https://github.com/imbryk/LoopingViewPager) lib.

The doc says: When you use Fragments, you have to add 2 "fake" fragments additionally to your mFragmentList, what I'm doing here:

```
       var adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(LogItemPage(logItems.filter { it.type!!.equals(LogItemType.Basic) }),
                getString(R.string.fragment_main_basic_title));
        adapter.addFragment(LogItemPage(logItems.filter { it.type!!.equals(LogItemType.Extended) }),
                getString(R.string.fragment_main_extended_title));

// add two extra Fragments of the same Fragments:

 adapter.addFragment(LogItemPage(logItems.filter { it.type!!.equals(LogItemType.Basic) }),
                getString(R.string.fragment_main_basic_title));
        adapter.addFragment(LogItemPage(logItems.filter { it.type!!.equals(LogItemType.Extended) }),
                getString(R.string.fragment_main_extended_title));

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and in my ViewPagerAdapter:

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {

    var position2 = LoopViewPager.toRealPosition(position, mFragmentList.size);
    var count = mFragmentList.size
    var modulo = position2%count
    return mFragmentList[modulo]
}
```

But I get this error, when I try to swipe to the end of the viewpager - the first two real fragments are ok, but when I swipe to the end, so that the first one is shown again it crashes:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ch.zhaw.myapp.android.debug, PID: 9737
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change tag of fragment LogItemPage{16838b #1 id=0x7f0c0086 android:switcher:2131492998:0}: was android:switcher:2131492998:0 now android:switcher:2131492998:4
```

Here is an [example](https://github.com/imbryk/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/d0b93d6210679cd503319469fc323fbc45271b7d/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/SampleTabsStyled.java) which should work, I tried to adapt.